# wifi config on raspberry pi

Tags: wireless, raspberrypi

I used the raspbery pi image utility to create an ubuntu image. In the utility you can set the wifi settings before it create the image on the sdcard.
I was able to connect to my home wifi but I would like to connect to my phone hotspot.

How to change which ssid the ubuntu connects to?

What is the default connections manager?
I am running ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on raspberry pi

Thank you

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2? Or Ubuntu Server 22.04.2?